# The specified time zone isn't valid - using EWS from server

Tags: c#, datetime, exchange-server

I set appointment in MS Exchange from `ASP.NET MVC` application.

When i run code from my computer in Ukraine - everyghing is ok,

but when I deploy my code on server in Russia - it shows:

```
The specified time zone isn't valid.
```

I tried a lot of things but can't fix that. Please help me with this issue.

I use:

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
appointmet.Start;

Answer (score 0):

If some people just come accross the same issue, it has been reported as an issue in EWS api (cf https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/13) but seems most likely an issue in .NET's TimeZoneInfo parsing logic. An update of your .Net version might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
static TimeZoneInfo getCorrectTimeZone()
{
  return TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("Time zone to workaround a bug", TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset, "Time zone to workaround a bug", "Time zone to workaround a bug");
}

static ExchangeService getExchangeService()
{
  var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2, getCorrectTimeZone());
  return service;
}
```